# How to get last value from this array?

Tags: php, arrays, class

How to get the last array value of this var_dump?

I do a var_dump on a variable (`$submission`) and get this:

```
object(stdClass)#148 (8) {
  ["sid"]=> string(3) "199" 
  ["nid"]=> string(4) "3042" 
  ["submitted"]=> string(10) "1386113448" 
  ["remote_addr"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" 
  ["uid"]=> string(2) "21" 
  ["name"]=> string(8) "SClosson" 
  ["is_draft"]=> string(1) "0"  
  ["data"]=> array(1) {
    [1]=> array(1) {
      [0]=> string(8) "blahblah" 
    } 
  }
}
```

So I need to store `blahblah` in a variable from the above array, but how?

Thought I could just get it by doing this:  `$submission['data'][1][0]`, but that doesn't work.  How do I return blahblah from this?

Comment: http://us2.php.net/end

Comment: also objects are different than arrays, you are looking at an object actually... so $submission is an object and $submission->data is an array

Comment: I have also tried `$submission->$data[1][0]` and this doesn't give me anything...

Comment: print_r($submission->data) and post results..

Comment: I was using the `$data`, instead of just `data`.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need an array, you can type cast it

```
$result = (array) $submission;
```

Or as an object, access the data as public properties

```
echo $submission->data[1][0];
```

Comment: No, I need the value of `blahblah` in a variable of type `string`

Comment: Sorry, that actually did it.  Thanks

Comment: also objects are different than arrays, you are looking at an object actually... so $submission is an object and $submission->data is an array – skrilled 25 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_pop if you want to get the last value of an array.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php